# bootstrap pills how to display the pills tab without scrolling on bootstrap 5

Tags: navigation, nav, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 and I want to display 3 tables on the same div and navigate between them using nav pills but the problem I have is that when I click on nav for 1st time the table will display correctly but it will automatically scroll to the top of the page a
this my nav pills

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills " >
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a href="#a" class="nav-link active"  data-toggle="tab"> a</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a href="#b" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab"> b</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                              <a href="#c" class="nav-link"  data-toggle="tab">c</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code require to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, the problem you are running into is caused by the fact that you are using Anchor tags (`<a>`), rather than buttons. Anchors are meant for navigation, hence why you are being brought to the top of the page. I believe the portion of the documentation you are following is the part meant for navigation bars, rather than tabbed interfaces.

The documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior) should give you the result you are looking for. Note that it uses buttons instead of anchors, and depends on JavaScript to provide the dynamic appearance.